# GitHub API Access denied trying to update a workflow via API

Tags: api, github, workflow

I created a public repository within my personal account, created a PAT w/ the workflow permissions checked, but am unable to disable the workflow via the API as I receive a message stating that I must have admin rights to the repository. I believe the PAT has the correct permissions so I’m unsure as to why this isn’t working.

Here is the command I am attempting to use (based on the documentation):

```
curl -s christronyxyocum:MY-PAT -X PUT -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/MY-USERNAME/MY-REPO/actions/workflows/workflow.yml/disable
```

I can retrieve information about the workflow without any issues so I believe that I have the correct URL and formatting, etc. I have even tried creating a new PAT with the same permissions and that one experiences the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. Rather than using the `username:token` format like they show repeatedly in their documentation, you must use the `-H "Authorization: bearer TOKEN"` header with the `curl` command.